# In SP2010, with a 3 step serial approval workflow, how can I change a field value each time a workflow step is approved?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a 3 step serial approval using SharePoint Designer using the "Start approval process". Is there a way to have a list item field value change or update each time one of the steps are approved?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a action as **Set field as "Your Value"**

Comment: Yes of course that's what I'd use but I do not know where to place that for each approval step, do you? So that every time a step is completed a value is changed.

Comment: can you just put some steps you are using it in your designer. Ideally it should be straight forward after the approval is happening. An If-Else condition is set up which will have a Set as Field on Approval. Also you can have a Boolean variable set as true and once the Step completes the variable is set as false so that the step doesn't  trigger again.